# Xcode lost track of corresponding ViewController making a Reference Outlet

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have built a Xamarin iOS app in Visual Studio for Mac using Xcode to edit the UI storyboard.  The app runs great.  I even have it in Apple Connect and a tester is testing it.

I need to create a Referencing Outlet in Xcode, for a Text Field but Xcode is not doing the right thing when I Ctrl-drag the Text Field control to the corresponding .h file.  Here are two descriptions of the problem.

**Description I**

I have followed the directions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/creating-ui-objects?tabs=windows) using the Assistant in Xcode.

The Assistant displays the storyboard and a code file side by side, like it should.  When I click on a control in the Scene I want to work with (ContactUs) a generic UIViewController (UiViewController.h) displays in the code side.  My ThirdViewController should display.

The generic file that displays has this in a comment near the top of the file.

```
UIViewController is a generic controller base class that manages a view.  It has methods that are called when a view appears or disappears.
```

When I click on my Home Scene the FirstViewController displays in the code side.  I think that is correct.

**Description II**

When I display the storyboard and the FirstViewController.h file side by side - NOT using the assistant - and I Ctrl-drag a control in the Home Scene to FirstViewController.h, Xcode offers the Outlets popup just fine.

[image]

When I display the storyboard and the ThirdViewController.h file side by side - NOT using the assistant - and I Ctrl-drag a control in the ContactUs Scene to ThirdViewController.h, Xcode does not offer the Outlets popup.

So it seems that Xcode has lost track of my ThirdViewController.

What do I need to do to create an Outlet in the ThirdViewController.h file using the Ctrl-drag approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select your controller in the storyboard, did you check the Identity inspector in the right panel to make sure that your class is set in the CustomClass > Class field?

[image]